# How to automatically answer the "'Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page" warning message in browser?

Tags: c#, browser, popup

Is it possible to automatically answer the pop that says, "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" in C#.

I want to be able to confirm leaving the page and not make the user have to manually select it. So, have it click on 'Yes, I want to leave.'

Is this possible?

Comment: Read the question, people.  It's not asking how to show the message box, it's asking how to bypass it.

Comment: `I want to be able to confirm leaving the page and not make the user have to manually select it.` Is the website yours?

Comment: I want to bypass and leave the page. Basically confirm 'Yes, I want to go away.' No it's not my website.

Comment: @Vanna webBrowser